# MySQL truncates argument that causes an exception

Tags: python, mysql, flask, exception, mysql-python

I am implementing some error handling in my web application:

```
import parse

try:
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO User (email, name, hash) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s');" % (email, name, pw_hash))
except MySQLdb.IntegrityError as e:
    msg = e.args[1]
    print(email)
    print(e)
    if "Duplicate entry" in msg: 
        fields = parse("Duplicate entry '{}' for key '{}'", msg)
        msg = "%s %s already exists." % (fields[1], fields[0])
        raise ConflictException(msg) //sends response to client with status code 409
```

The problem is that the exception does not include whole string of the input  that caused the error.
When i test for duplicate emails i generate a reasonably valid email, when mysql tries to insert the email that already exists the `IntegrityError` is raised.

When i print the error versus the input email the email in the error has been truncated:

The actual input email:

```
a+EMCayiy_O+xGVcYZxvZqHZTMv9-6aE2qSElp7LHQIdcmLMKbvlXo89nrUNsIFbplm36lVmQRvjzABDhGVab_LLvWQLDkyoMJakzb8FcacHnNgj642jLhbu5imT+ENxR01W-DcWTJdZPRo0V155UW@PakZ7hfY2I953-4ackKNoNrJbcHkcwNGruEvprdAFgz2xpVvTbzt0LMxHZEgNYuA641Uj9AA1zC39B6C.VzCgqPzPj09bSqDyPNjDuZR
```

The error thrown by the database:

```
(1062, "Duplicate entry 'a+EMCayiy_O+xGVcYZxvZqHZTMv9-6aE2qSElp7LHQIdcmLMKbvlXo89nrUNsIFb' for key 'email'")
```

Because of this, my tests break:

```
def assert_register_fail(self, email, name, password, confirmed_password, expected_msg, expected_code):
    response = self.register(email, name, password, confirmed_password)
    res = json.loads(response.data.decode())
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, expected_code)
    self.assertEqual(res["message"], expected_msg)

def test_email_taken(self):
    email = self.gen_email()
    password = self.gen_pass()
    expected_msg = "email %s already exists." % email
    self.assert_register_success(email, self.gen_name(), password, password)
    self.assert_register_fail(email, self.gen_name(), password, password, expected_msg, 409)
```

The tests obviously expects the whole invalid email to be included in the error message:

```
AssertionError: 'emai[61 chars]5YD.q already exists.' != 'emai[61 chars]5YD.qq5Po.OYDxtaL-UcMDYx4Uw5aEth-+GWeMJrSat_fH[162 chars]sts.'
- email Jf5QbVi+l1x3VOrYYc5c-wlgg+s7b4TOHVQqHwtIT+rouTe1CQShWlX384d5YD.q already exists.
+ email Jf5QbVi+l1x3VOrYYc5c-wlgg+s7b4TOHVQqHwtIT+rouTe1CQShWlX384d5YD.qq5Po.OYDxtaL-UcMDYx4Uw5aEth-+GWeMJrSat_fHF6THMOwBOawCZo1Vu8.hJoWvH.l.LUYNwANrtgAy+vM.h@W884ZKLYhgknKSeDSCQxC9lLUYa3KSVXNKPUWxIyNXyK9De-FN-t935GBb3ma6b2wWel-L4xL2zM3Y6M.Qy5g3O-i2SMiE7PpsdALSUs already exists.
```

I could hack something together that uses another approach entirely but i don't think it would be better.

Also, i could limit the generated email length to around 60 characters at which point mysql does not truncate. The tests would pass but they might not reflect a real world scenario.

So, how do i retrieve the whole argument that caused the error from mysql?

Comment: How long is `email` in the table?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams varchar(255)